# Rails, RSpec: How to test, that a specific mailer action gets triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to ensure that running an importer results in sending out an email.

This is what I got so far:

```
describe '#import' do
  it 'triggers the correct mailer and action', :vcr do
    expect(OrderMailer).to receive(:delivery_confirmation).with(order)

    Importer.new(@file).import
    remove_backed_up_file
  end
end
```

It fails with:

```
pry(#<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TransactionManager>)> error
=> #<NoMethodError: undefined method `deliver_now' for nil:NilClass>
```

Which obviously can't work out as I am expecting the Mailer class to receive the (instance) method call. But how can I get a hold of the mailer instance that will receive the call? How would you test that a unit's method triggers a certain mailer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right,

```
expect_any_instance_of(OrderMailer).to receive(:delivery_confirmation).with(order)
```

will test the mailer instance that will receive the call.

For more precision you may want to set up your test with the particular instance of `OrderMailer` (let's say `order_mailer`) and write your expectation the following way

```
expect(order_mailer).to receive(:delivery_confirmation).with(order)
```

Comment: How would I be able to get a hold of the instance that will eventually receive the call? Just instanciating the class won't guarantee that this instance will be used by Rails, will it?

Comment: Sorry I have no experience with the mailers testing and can't answer how exactly you supposed to do that. But in general, you could stub `OrderMailer.new` or `OrderMailer.create` with your own `OrderMailer` instance to be sure that your test will handle exactly your instance. The example is `allow(OrderMailer).to receive(:create).and_return(order_mailer)`. `order_mailer` has to be created by that time.

Answer (score 3):

I assume the `delivery_confirmation` method in reality returns a `Mail` object. The problem is that `ActionMailer` will call the `deliver` method of the mail object. You've set an expectation stubbing out the `delivery_confirmation` method but you haven't specified what should be the return value. Try this

```
mail_mock = double(deliver: true)
# or mail_mock = double(deliver_now: true)
expect(mail_mock).to receive(:deliver)
# or expect(mail_mock).to receive(:deliver_now)
allow(OrderMailer).to receive(:delivery_confirmation).with(order).and_return(mail_mock)
# the rest of your test code
```

Comment: Your solution mocks Mailer implementation pretty well.

Although, instead of:

`expect(mail_mock).to receive(:deliver_now)` 

I suggest

`allow(mail_mock).to receive(:deliver_now)`.

In Your example ` expect ` is an assertion that deliver will be called at least one time and I think it is nice to mock this mailer in `before(:each) block of code`.